# Simple float operation

Tags: php

why does the next operation fails to show me a float with 8 decimals?

```
echo round(round(10/100,8) * round(0.00003,8),8);

echo '<br>';

echo round(0.1 * 0.0003,8);
```

outputs

```
3.0E-6
3.0E-5
```

Basically I'm trying to get 10% value out of a float number.

Thank you!

Comment: to display the number without the expondent - but as a decimal, try using either `sprintf` or `printf` ~ ie: `printf('%8f',$float_number);`

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct: it's the exponential notation. Essentially the number following the `E` is the exponent on base 10. If you need to print the decimal digits there is a specific function for that, which is [number_format](http://php.net/function.number_format).

`number_format(round(round(10/100,8) * round(0.00003,8),8), 8)`